# Глобальная перемена JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var a;
var b;
function update(input)
{
   a = $(input);
   b = a.val().length;
   // далее код с переменные работает 
}
```

вот вызов функции

```
 $("#jack").click(function () {
            update(this);
        });
```

Но сразу при выходе из функции эти переменные равны undefined
Почему обнуляются??

Comment: А где вызов функции, которая их изменит? Кстати, глобальные переменные - зло.

Comment: Хорошо, покажите ещё, где вы проверяете эти переменные. Внутри обработчика click?

Comment: @vp_arth - Сто против одного, что переменные проверяются/выводятся сразу после определения функции `function update(input) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

Не равно `undefined`. Всё нормально.

Проверьте, где вы вызываете функцию и получаете переменные. Если вы вызываете позже чем получаете, то будет `undefined`

Вызов до получения:

```js
var a;
var b;

function update(input) {
  a = $(input);
  b = a.val().length;
  // далее код с переменные работает 
}

update('.input');

console.log('a: '+a);
console.log('b: '+b);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="input">
```

Вызов после получения:

```js
var a;
var b;

function update(input) {
  a = $(input);
  b = a.val().length;
  // далее код с переменные работает 
}

console.log('a: '+a);
console.log('b: '+b);

update('.input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="input">
```